# Need to know the labor time or book times to replace a automatic transmission in a 2017 Dodge journey 2.4 l automatic transmission front wheel drive

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, journey, parts-replacement, book-hours

I need to know the flag hours to remove and replace a transmission in a 2017 Dodge journey 2.4 l front wheel drive